# Google Protocol Buffer C++ on ubuntu

Tags: buffer, protocols

I want to use Google protocol buffer in c++ on Ubuntu in first step I created .proto file

```
package business;
message Employee
{ 
required string first_name = 1;
required string last_name = 2;
required string email = 3;
}

message Company
{
required string name = 1;
optional string url = 2;
repeated Employee employee = 3;
}
```

I can easily translate it to the C++ data access classes by calling:

```
protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. business.proto
```

after this step protoc create to file

```
business.pb.h
business.pb.cc
```

when I want compile this code I see error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "business.pb.h"

using namespace std;

/// Saves a demo company object to 'company.bin'.
void save()
{
    business::Company company;
    company.set_name("Example Ltd.");
    company.set_url("http://www.example.com");

    // 1st employee
    {
        business::Employee *employee = company.add_employee();
        employee->set_first_name("John");
        employee->set_last_name("Doe");
        employee->set_email("john.doe@example.com");
    }

    // 2nd employee
    {
        business::Employee *employee = company.add_employee();
        employee->set_first_name("Jane");
        employee->set_last_name("Roe");
        employee->set_email("jane.roe@example.com");
    }

    fstream output("company.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
    company.SerializeToOstream(&output);
}

/// Loads a demo company object from 'company.bin' and dumps its data.
void load()
{
    business::Company company;
    fstream input("company.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

    company.ParseFromIstream(&input);
    cout << "Company: " << company.name() << "\n";
    cout << "URL: " << (company.has_url() ? company.url() : "N/A") << "\n";

    cout << "\nEmployees: \n\n";
    for(int i = 0, n = company.employee_size(); i < n; ++i)
    {
        const business::Employee &employee = company.employee(i);
        cout << "First name: " << employee.first_name() << "\n";
        cout << "Last name: " << employee.last_name() << "\n";
        cout << "Email: " << employee.email() << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    save();
    load();
    return 0;
}
```

for compile I use this command

```
g++ p1.cpp business.pb.cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`
```

but I see this error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/soQ3Z.png

Comment: Please turn this into a SSCCE and *please* do provide the output *text*.

Comment: how turn this into a SSCCE ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem 
1)uninstall old version Google Protocol Buffer
2) instal new version Google Protocol Buffer